# Parsing the server logs using shell scripts

Tags: shell, parsing, logging

I have the following log in my server. If we look at column 1, the entries could be a single IP address (117.199.183.116) or multiple Ip address (115.248.95.5, 115.112.231.105) 
Since space is the delimiter between the various entries in a line so using **cut -d " " -f 1,10** to separate columns will give different results for line 1 and line 2. So can anyone tell me how to solve this problem of getting the exact result.

```
117.199.183.116 - [11/Dec/2013:23:00:29 -0600] "GET /promotions/getConfig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2841 36 TLSv1 DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
115.248.95.5, 115.112.231.105 - [11/Dec/2013:23:00:29 -0600] "GET /promotions/getConfig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3142 36 TLSv1 DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
182.243.43.29 - [11/Dec/2013:23:00:29 -0600] "GET /promotions/getConfig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3124 36 TLSv1 DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
182.127.213.39 - [11/Dec/2013:23:00:29 -0600] "GET /promotions/getConfig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2933 36 TLSv1 DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
```

**The expected output is:**

```
117.199.183.116 36
115.248.95.5, 115.112.231.105 36
182.243.43.29 36
1182.127.213.39 36
```

To be more exact the log entries are something like

```
222.86.58.126 - [17/Dec/2013:08:21:40 -0600] "GET /promotions/getConfig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1505 36 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"i TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
218.95.69.175, 22.234.234.12 - [17/Dec/2013:08:21:40 -0600] "GET /promotions/getConfig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1477 36 "http://www.duba.com/static/js/storage/storage.swf?v=2&fun=swfStorage._init" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"i TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
```

So can there be a more generic solution so that we can pick any two columns.

Comment: Whether you need the ip address only or you going to do some modification in other field.

Comment: What is your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk '{s=$0; sub(/ -.*$/, "", s); k=0;
     for (i=5; i<=NF-3; i++) if ($i ~ /^HTTP\//) {k=i; break} print s, $(k+3)}' file.log
117.199.183.116 36
115.248.95.5, 115.112.231.105 36
182.243.43.29 36
182.127.213.39 36
```

Comment: What if in the columns after 36 there exists few entries which have spaces in between then ie. instead of DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA there is DHE-RSA-SEED SHA for one of the entry then  {$NF-2)} will also fail. Can there be a generic solution of the same.

Comment: Check the updated code now, it should work with any # of fields in the log lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the all repeated ip address from the single line, try this

```
  sed 's/\([0-9.,]*\)-\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the IP address and the 2nd last column,  try this one

```
 sed -r 's/(.*) - .* ([0-9]+) .*/\1 \2/'
```

Comment: This is just an example. I require any column after the ist column.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your log message, the line starts with IP Address/es followed by a '-' and then a timestamp and smoe other data.
I would advice you to perform a cut using '-' as the delimiter, take up the f1 as your IP address, and you can make the rest into another string, which you may then de-limit by space if required.

Comment: If you look at the expected output, you'll see that there's an extra field `36` that needs to be parsed out from the log line. So your solution almost works, but not quite.